# Find first occurrence of list item above specific class - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a list, and I'm trying to select the last occurrence of the 'nav-header' class in the list above the only list item with the class of 'active'.

```
<li class="nav-header"><a href="#" class="slide" id="general">Main</a></li>
<li class="general"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
<li class="general"><a href="faq.php">FAQ</a></li>
<li class="general"><a href="wiki.php">Wiki</a></li>
<li class="general"><a href="tos.php">TOS</a></li>
<li class="general"><a href="helpdesk.php">Help Desk</a></li>
<li class="general"><a href="development.php">Changelog</a></li>
<li class="general"><a href="tokens.php">Tokens</a></li>
<li class="general"><a href="stats.php">Stats</a></li>
<li class="nav-header"><a href="#" class="slide" id="community">Community</a></li>
<li class="community"><a href="notepad.php">Notepad</a></li>
<li class="community"><a href="messaging.php">Messaging</a></li>
<li class="community"><a href="forums/vforum.php?page=1">Main Forum</a></li>
<li class="community"><a href="cforum/vforum.php?page=1">Network Forum</a></li>
<li class="community"><a href="online.php">Currently Online</a></li>
<li class="community active"><a href="find.php">Search</a></li>
<li class="community"><a href="gm.php">Global Market</a></li>
<li class="community"><a href="bm.php">Black Market</a></li>
<li class="community"><a href="mostwanted.php">Most Wanted</a></li>
```

For example, when the 'Search' list item is active, I want to find and return ONLY the Community list item. I can get it to return both Community and Main via the .prevAll function, but can't for the life of me figure out how to return just one. Thanks for the help.

Comment: So you want to select just `<li class="nav-header"><a href="#" class="slide" id="community">Community</a></li>`?

Comment: Yes, if one of the li under community is active. If one above it is active, the Main li should be selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the `:first` selector, see the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4eyhJ/).

```
$('li.active').prevAll('.nav-header:first')
```